# Not able to do operation with other role then Superuser

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I use spring boot 2 with spring security and thymeleaf

I have many role

Superuser
CustomerSupport
Integrator

In my class

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig{

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEventPublisher authenticationEventPublisher;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private CustomLogoutHandler customLogoutHandler;

    @Configuration
    public class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationEventPublisher(authenticationEventPublisher).userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/css/**", "/webjars/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/")
                    .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutHandler)
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")) .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID") .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").and().csrf().disable();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/webjars/**", "/js/**", "/img/**");
        }
    }

}
```

In thymeleaf, I have in some place this kind of code

```
<th:block sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('CustomerSupport')">
    ....
</th:block>
```

When I connect with user without this role, I see nothing, normal.

In a rest controller I have

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('Superuser', 'Integrator', CustomerSupport') ")
@PutMapping(value = "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity updateCar(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @RequestBody CarDto dto) {
    ...
}
```

When a user with the role: CustomerSupport call updateCar, He get

{
  "timestamp" : "2018-10-30T11:36:46.603+0000",
  "status" : 403,
  "error" : "Forbidden",
  "message" : "Forbidden",
  "path" : "/rest/car/5000"
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `'` in this line for CustomerSupport.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('Superuser', 'Integrator', 'CustomerSupport') "
```